# React error in showing an arrow with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

So my App.js is:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Card from './users/Card';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the Card.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    const people = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
    const peopleList = people.map(person => <p>{person}</p>);
    return (
      {peopleList}
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {peopleList}). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

What am I doing wrong? If I use the map function in the `App.js` it works fine.

Comment: It's just as the error says. By returning `{peopleList}`, you're returning an object with one property, `peopleList`. Return the array instead, not an object

Comment: @CertainPerformance Nopes, that's completely fine. It's about the way it's returned.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman If it were completely fine, OP wouldn't be running into the error, right? Returning an object instead of an array (or a fragment) is the base problem here, isn't it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I meant, an object with one property ... er... You are kinda right, I misunderstood! He he.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `return peopleList;`

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-lichterman-h7vwr)

Answer (score 1):

Use a fragment:

```
return <>{peopleList}</>;
```

Full code:

```js
class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    const people = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
    const peopleList = people.map(person => <p>{person}</p>);
    return <>{peopleList}</>;
  }
}
```

**Demo:** [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-fast-hc8r5)

Comment: Thanks. Why do I need to enclose it in a div tag?

Comment: Coz it's JSX while you are in JS mode. 